# Can I use a trackball in substitution of a fader to write automation on Pro Tools?

Tags: pro-tools, post-production, mouse, trackball

I know I could click on the digital fader of the track in the mix window and write automation that way, but I recently found an app called "AudioSwift" that turns your Trackpad into a multitool "Fader, X,Y slider, Beat creator, etc". However, I **don't** have a trackpad, I have a Kensington Expert Trackball mouse.
So, I was wondering if anyone knows how to use the trackball that way?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried simply plugging it in and giving it a crack?